# Flex Drag & Drop: Detecting when all data has been moved from source to destination

Tags: apache-flex, events, flex3, event-handling

I have two `mx:TileList` controls that I'm using to allow editing of objects in batch. The first contains a collection of all available data, and the 2nd contains the current batch. Both are bound to `ArrayCollections`, and using the native drag-n-drop functionality of the TileList control the data is moved from one `ArrayCollection` to the other when an object is dragged between them.

I need to change the `currentState` to show & reset the batch manipulation controls when the batch count goes from **0** to **n** or **n** to **0** items. Based on [the documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=dragdrop_8.html), I would have thought that I should listen to the `dragComplete` event, but my testing shows that instead of firing after the data has been removed from the source ArrayCollection and added to the destination ArrayCollection, it fires (consistently) between these two actions.

Both lists are similar to this:

```
<mx:TileList 
    id="srcList" 
    dragEnabled="true" 
    dropEnabled="true" 
    dragMoveEnabled="true" 
    dataProvider="{images}"
    dragComplete="handleDragComplete(event)"
    allowMultipleSelection="true"
/>
```

And here's the source of the `handleDragComplete` function:

```
private function handleDragComplete(e:DragEvent):void{
    trace(e.dragInitiator.name + '.dragComplete: batch.length=' + batch.length.toString());
    trace(e.dragInitiator.name + '.dragComplete: images.length=' + images.length.toString());
    if (batch.length > 0){
        currentState = 'show';
    }else{
        currentState = '';
    }
}
```

And lastly, here's some example output from running the code. These are all run one after the other.

**Case 1:**

The application loads with 10 objects in the first list and the batch is empty. I dragged 1 object from the source list to the batch list.

```
srcList.dragComplete: batch.length=1
srcList.dragComplete: images.length=10
```

(Expected: 1,9)

Clearly, the object has been added to the batch ArrayCollection but not removed from the source.

**Case 2:**

Now, I'll drag a 2nd object into the batch.

```
srcList.dragComplete: batch.length=2
srcList.dragComplete: images.length=9
```

(Expected: 2,8)

Firstly, we can see that images.length has changed, showing that the object that I dragged from the source list to the batch list was removed **AFTER** the dragComplete event fired.

The same thing happens this time: The new object is added to the batch ArrayCollection (batch.length=2), the `dragComplete` event fires (running these traces), and then the object is removed from the source ArrayCollection.

**Case 3:**

Now, I'll drag both images from the batch list back to their original location in the source list.

```
batchList.dragComplete: batch.length=2
batchList.dragComplete: images.length=10
```

(Expected: 0,10)

We can see that batch.length hasn't gone down, but the source images array is back at its original length of 10.

**QUESTION:** Am I doing something wrong? Is there another event I could listen for? (*Note: I tried both* `DragExit` *and* `DragDrop`*, just to be sure, and those behave as expected, but are not what I need.*) Or is there another way to get the data that I want? Or... have I found a bug in the SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you listen for a collectionChange event on your target ArrayCollections?

```
batch.addEventListener(CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE, handleBatchCollectionChange);
```

Comment: Yes, this did exactly what I need. Thank you! I'll edit my code into your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution that worked for me well.

```
private function dragBeginHandler():void {
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dragFinishHandler);
    trace("Drag/drop started, Drag-completion listener added");
}

private function dragFinishHandler():void {
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dragFinishHandler);
    trace("Drag/drop finished, Drag-completion listener removed");

    //do or print whatever you want to do here, add/remove will be done by now
    trace('dragComplete: batch.length=' + batch.length.toString());
    trace('dragComplete: images.length=' + images.length.toString());

    if (batch.length > 0){
            currentState = 'show';
    }else{
            currentState = '';
    }
}

<mx:TileList 
        id="srcList" 
        dragStart="dragBeginHandler()"
        dragEnabled="true" 
        dropEnabled="true" 
        dragMoveEnabled="true" 
        dataProvider="{images}"
        dragComplete="handleDragComplete(event)"
        allowMultipleSelection="true"
/>
```